# Django accepting QueryParams (Must be callable error)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'd like `http://example.com/view_item/4` to handle a view for a selected object by passing the object ID, but after trying every combination I've found online of what *will work*, I'm still getting the following error:

```
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

This is my path:

```
 url(r'^view_item/(?P<query>\w+)$','view_item')]
```

I've verified the regex, I've tried without the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting, as the error stated, to include the callable view. My confusion comes from mixed methods in learning resources.

Working path example:

```
url(r'^view_item/(?P<query>\w+)$',view_item, 'view_item')]
```